# Build multi level array of arrays/jagged array from parsed string

Tags: c#, regex, string, parsing, jagged-arrays

I have been trying to expand my code to incorporate a 3rd level array based on some strings, this is what I've been trying to do but i can only make it to a second level array with my understanding of the code.

```
string a = "{50,8,10} Grade 1; {70,10,45} Grade 2; {80,20,65} Grade 3: {90,100,23} Grade 4; {98,99,32} Grade 5; {100,1000,7} Grade 6";

        int[][][] test =
            a.Split(':')
             .Select(t => Regex.Matches(t, @"(?<={).*?(?=})"))
             .Cast<MatchCollection>()
             .Select(m => m.Cast<Match>()
                 .Select(n => n.ToString().Split(',')
                     .Select(int.Parse))
                     .ToArray())
                 .ToArray()
             .ToArray();
```

so each section of the array would look something like this

```
        //int[][][] { {50,8,10} Grade 1; {70,10,45} Grade 2; {80,20,65} Grade 3 }
        //    int[][] { {50,8,10},{70,10,45},{80,20,65} }
        //        int[] {50,8,10}
```

anyway I'm still quite new to programming and I've been just diving into it and learning as I go. if there is a more efficient way of handling this besides using arrays I'm open to suggestions,

Comment: Have you looked at the Dictionary<>?

Comment: No, I will have to take a look at that.

Comment: What are you trying to model? Don't fit your model to the storage type - work out what you want to store, then store it :-)

Comment: so the big picture is this, I have a string that is randomly pulled from a file, a typical one looks like this    | | | | | | | 3 | {10,0} d4; {20,0} d6; {30,0} d8; {40,0} d10; {50,0} d12; {60,0} d20; {70,0} d30; {80,0} %d10; {90,0} d100; {100,0} d1000 : {0,0,0} test1; {0,0,0} test2 : {0,0,0} test3 |    the code parses through the line to find values between | and places them in memory for usage later, the values are always different and the arrays within the string that are pulled out are always different. So i need it to look for markers that identify what is what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is actually almost right.   I think there was just a `)` out of place (I cleaned up the formatting a bit too).

```
int[][][] test = a.Split(':')
                  .Select(t => Regex.Matches(t, @"(?<={).*?(?=})"))
                  .Cast<MatchCollection>()
                  .Select(m => m.Cast<Match>()
                                .Select(n => n.ToString().Split(',')
                                              .Select(int.Parse)
                                              .ToArray())
                                .ToArray())
                  .ToArray();
```

An `int[][][]` is not the most effective data structure, though - you might want to consider `Dictionary<string, List<int>>` instead.

Comment: oh wow, I was racking my brain over that one, I just couldn't figure out what I was doing wrong so I rewrote that thing like 12 times to no avail.